# There is any method to send feedback about routes in the Here Routing Service?

Tags: routes, here-api, feedback

I want to know if there is any method, where I can send feedback about a incorrect route when I'm using hazmat parameters on the HERE Routing Service.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact issue that you are facing. It would be helpful if you could provide the request and response and expected result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.